# How to make TMemo treat new lines in Linux style?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tmemo

I have a string that contains Linux style line breaks. Linux style is `#13` while Windows style is `#13#10`.

I would like to show this string in a `TMemo`. Looks like `TMemo` accepts only Windows style and does not treat `#13` as a new line.

Is the only way for `TMemo` to format new lines is to insert `#10`, or can I somehow ask `TMemo` to act in Linux style?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to show this string in Memo. Looks like Memo accepts only Windows style and does not treat #$13 as new line.

That depends on how you give the `string` to the Memo.

The underlying Win32 `EDIT` control that `TMemo` wraps only supports `#13#10` style line breaks internally.

If you assign the `string` to the `TMemo.Text` property, it will just pass the `string` as-is to the underlying Win32 control.  So, the `string` will need to use Windows-style line breaks only.

However, if you assign the `string` to the `TMemo.Lines.Text` property instead, it will internally adjust all styles of line breaks to Windows-style, and then give the adjusted `string` to the Win32 control.  So, in that regard, you can handle Linux-style and Windows-style line breaks equally.

Alternatively, the `TStringList` class supports parsing all styles of line breaks (when its `LineBreak` property matches the `sLineBreak` constant, which it does by default). So, another option would be to first assign the `string` to the `TStringList.Text` property, and then you can assign the resulting list to the `TMemo.Lines` property.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Linux style is #10, not #13 (#13 is MacOS style, AFAIK). Also, note that it's #10 and not #$10 (which is #16).

The easiest way would be to replace the line ends on load/save, ie. instead of

```
Memo.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName)
or
Memo.Lines.Text := STR;
```

do

```
uses System.IOUtils;

Memo.Lines.Text := TFile.ReadAllText(FileName,TEncoding.UTF8).Replace(#13#10,#13).Replace(#10,#13).Replace(#13,#13#10)
or
Memo.Lines.Text := STR.Replace(#13#10,#13).Replace(#10,#13).Replace(#13,#13#10)
```

and instead of

```
Memo.Lines.SaveToFile(FileName)
or
STR := Memo.Lines.Text
```

do

```
uses System.IOUtils;

TFile.WriteAllText(Memo.Lines.Text.Replace(#13#10,#13),TEncoding.UTF8)
or
STR := Memo.Lines.Text.Replace(#13#10,#13)
```

Of course, you should replace the TEncoding.UTF8 with the appropriate encoding you want to use.

Comment: Another possible option is to use the Memo.Lines.LineBreak property.

Comment: @MarkF: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in a Memo.Lines TStrings descendant. When you read the text out using Memo.Lines.Text it always returns it with #13#10 line breaks (due to an optimization that reads the entire Memo from Windows instead of reading it line-by-line, I believe). Also, whether or not you set LineBreak when assigning to Memo.Lines.Text, it supports #10 line breaks fine.

Comment: When you assign a string to `TMemo.Lines.Text`, internally it adjusts all styles of line breaks to `#13#10` and then sends a `WM_SETTEXT` message to the underlying window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const lf = chr(13) + chr(10);
var ls  : string; // Linux Style String
    lfs : string; // Windows Style String

begin
  lfs := stringreplace(ls,#13,lf,[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);     
end;
```